# JS Equivalent of PHP's "strtotime('-11 month')"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, date, strtotime

Is there an simple way to get the date of 11 months ago, in Javascript or even with JQuery involved. Equivalent of using PHP's `strtotime('-11 month')`. I know you can easily add/substract days in JS's `Date` object, but months are a little more complicated without involving all the days of each month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this'll help you out.

**http://phpjs.org/functions/strtotime/**

PHPJS is an amazing site, wich has a lot more than just this. And it's all plain JS, no jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [moment](http://momentjs.com/):

```
moment().subtract('months', 11).toDate()
```

Answer (score 0):

I love the php way, and combined locutus (phpjs) into a small javascript class/function as an alternative:

http://tools.bitfertig.de/datebob.js/

```
datebob('-11 month')
```